# Users created posts not being returned to template? Django

Tags: django

the user is able to create a post and it will be shown the in the list. I've also created a users profile/summary page where the user can edit/delete their posts.

Currently, it's showing blank and I'm not quite sure why?Am I supposed to get the instance or is it fine the way it is?

**Model**

```
class Aircraft(AircraftModelBase):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    manufacturer = SortableForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    aircraft_type = SortableForeignKey(AircraftType)
```

**View**

```
def upload_overview(request):
    uploaded_aircraft = Aircraft.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'account/upload_overview.html',{'UploadedAircraft':uploaded_aircraft})
```

**Template**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row aircraft">
      {% if UploadedAircraft %}
      {% for upload in UploadedAircraft %}
        <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-sm-3 item">
            <div class="box"><a href="{{ upload.aircraft.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ upload.aircraft.image.url }}" width="200px" height="200px" alt="{{ upload.aircraft.title }}"/></a>
                <h3 class="name"><a href="{{ upload.aircraft.get_absolute_url }}">{{ upload.aircraft.name }}</a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
              <h2 class="text-center">No uploaded aircraft posts..</h2></div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you logged in your webapp?

Comment: Try to print request.user in template

Comment: Yes I am.......

Comment: Am I supposed to get the instance or is it fine the way it is?

Comment: Your code seems fine..try to print uploaded_aircraft in view..and report what you see

Comment: It's returning the objects, but not displaying them in the template?

Comment: I got it working! It was supposed to {{ upload.name }} instead of {{ upload.aircraft.name }}

Comment: yes..just was gonna comment that